# How to concat data if its NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a Table as shown below

```
mysql> desc document;

+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| T1              | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| T2              | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| T3              | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| T4              | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| T5              | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
======================================================
```

And this is data present inside the document

```
mysql> select * from document ;

+-------------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+
| T1                   | T2          | T3          | T4   | T5   |
+-------------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+
| Chips And Chocolates | Yummy Chips | NULL        | NULL | NULL |
| Chips And Chocolates | Yummy Chips | Lemon Masti | NULL | NULL |
+-------------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+------+------+
```

A Row can have all T1 , T2 , T3 , T4 , T5 filled up

Or it can have NULL values

Is it possible to combine data into comma seperated in case its null

For example

**In First case**

```
Chips And Chocolates,Yummy Chips
```

**In Second  case**

```
Chips And Chocolates,Yummy Chips, Lemon Masti
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
FROM documents
```

See also the docs for [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), it has the advantage that it skips a value if it is `null`.

Comment: I mean what is INSERT TABLE ID HERE

Comment: It is a key you want to group by. Can be your primary key, foreign key, or another column-name. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Using `GROUP_BY` seems unnecessary here. If you group by a row id then it will have no effect and grouping by something else could cause missed values. Otherwise the use of `CONCAT_WS` is correct. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90e29/4

Comment: @DatRid , should i use GROUP BY  in my query , because its working without using Group By also .

Comment: As Jim said, it is unnecessary here. I just wanted you to explain what it is. I actually see no use for GroupBy

Comment: @DatRid you are right, I'll take it away, I was thinking and linked the wrong function!